# Swiper: при пролистывании следующий слайдер будто бы не "долистывает" до середины

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

Лучше покажу на скринах. На первом скрине видно, как слайдер выглядит изначально, тут проблем нет. Но затем, при пролистывании слайда, второй уже выглядит так (2 скрин), а третий ещё хуже (3 скрин), далее все хуже и хуже. Как я писал, он будто бы не "долистывается" и я не знаю, как это решить. Пытался команде `slidesPerView` и значение `1`, и значение `'auto'`, но тщетно. Советовали отцентрировать слайды с помощью `centeredSlides: true`, но результат не меняется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема и как это решить.

Скрины:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```js
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';

const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  breakpoints: {
    320: {
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      centeredSlides: true,
    }
  }
  });
```

```css
    .repair__brands__container {
      margin-left: 24px;

      .repair__brands {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-top: 40px;
        column-gap: 32px;
        row-gap: 16px;

        .repair__brands__blocks {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: end;
          align-items: center;
          width: 240px;
          height: 72px;
          border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
          border-radius: 6px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .repair__brands__blocks:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid #303030;
      }

      .repair__brands-hidden {
        display: flex;
        column-gap: 32px;
      }
    }


 @media (max-width: 320px) {
    .repair {
      margin-top: 40px;
      width: 100%;

      .repair__brands__container {
        margin-left: 16px;

        .repair__brands {
          flex-wrap: nowrap;
          width: 280px;
          margin-top: 32px;

          .repair__blocks__wrapper {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;

            .repair__brands__blocks {
              width: 240px;
            }
            #more-1.off-1 {
              display: none;
            }
          }
        }
        .repair__more {
          display: none;
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="repair__brands__container swiper">
            <div class="repair__brands swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="repair__blocks__wrapper swiper-slide">
                <div class="repair__brands__blocks">
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-image repair__brands__blocks-lenovo"
                    src="./img/lenovo_block.png"
                    alt="lenovo"
                  />
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-more"
                    src="./img/more_block.svg"
                    alt="more"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="repair__blocks__wrapper swiper-slide">
                <div class="repair__brands__blocks">
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-image repair__brands__blocks-samsung"
                    src="./img/samsung_block.png"
                    alt="samsung"
                  />
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-more"
                    src="./img/more_block.svg"
                    alt="more"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="repair__blocks__wrapper swiper-slide">
                <div class="repair__brands__blocks">
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-image repair__brands__blocks-apple"
                    src="./img/apple_block.png"
                    alt=""
                    apple
                  />
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-more"
                    src="./img/more_block.svg"
                    alt="more"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="repair__blocks__wrapper swiper-slide">
                <div class="repair__brands__blocks">
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-image repair__brands__blocks-viewsonic"
                    src="./img/viewsonic_block.png"
                    alt="viewsonic"
                  />
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-more"
                    src="./img/more_block.svg"
                    alt="more"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="repair__blocks__wrapper swiper-slide">
                <div class="repair__brands__blocks">
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-image repair__brands__blocks-bosch"
                    src="./img/bosch_block.png"
                    alt="bosch"
                  />
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-more"
                    src="./img/more_block.svg"
                    alt="more"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="repair__blocks__wrapper swiper-slide">
                <div class="repair__brands__blocks">
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-image repair__brands__blocks-hp"
                    src="./img/hp_block.png"
                    alt="hp"
                  />
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-more"
                    src="./img/more_block.svg"
                    alt="more"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- <div class="repair__brands-hidden off-1" id="more-1">
                <div class="repair__brands__blocks repair__acer swiper-slide">
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-image repair__brands__blocks-acer"
                    src="./img/acer_block.png"
                    alt="acer"
                  />
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-more"
                    src="./img/more_block.svg"
                    alt="more"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="repair__brands__blocks repair__sony swiper-slide">
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-image repair__brands__blocks-sony"
                    src="./img/sony_block.png"
                    alt="sony"
                  />
                  <img
                    class="repair__brands__blocks-more"
                    src="./img/more_block.svg"
                    alt="more"
                  />
                </div>
              </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="repair__more">
              <img
                class="repair__more-image"
                src="./img/heading_read.svg"
                alt="show_all"
              />
              <button class="repair__more-btn" id="btn-1">Показать все</button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте инициализацию слайдера поставить в обработчике `window.onload`. Дело в том, что иногда размеры элементов меняются по мере загрузки страницы , поэтому в слайдере могут прописываться размеры слайдов больше ли меньше, чем нужно.

Comment: Это всё из-за gap. Он не умеет рассчитывать отступы я так понял. в общем думаю нужно ".swiper-slide" задать ширину и не фмксированную как вы задали в 240px, а например, если 2 элемента должно отображаться, то "width: 50%;", а если три то 33.33333% например. И этому же элементу мы уже задаём "padding: 15px;" например - это и будет типо отступ. Ну и ".swiper-wrapper" уберите "flex-wrap: wrap"- он же не должен переходить на вторую строчку? Точнее сказать не могу, так как не вижу как это на самом деле выглядит на странице.

Answer (score 0):

У слайдов слайдера swiper есть такие классы как active и prev. Придай им свойства как тут и все заработает, так как у меня была такая же проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)